# Where AWS stores the created AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy policy and how can I see it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, policies

I'm studying AWS EKS and I'm following the ufficial [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html). As explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html#lbc-create-policy) I created the "AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy" but I would like to check if it has been correctly created. How can I see the list of the created policies?

I'm asking because I already tried to create many of them with different names (like: *AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy**Test***, *AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy**Experiment***... etc) but, once created, I can't find them anywhere.

I tried to give a look [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?#/policies$customer) (the IAM policy manager) but as you can see from the following screenshot they are not listed. Is there a way? Also through a CLI command?
To be honest it will be really usefull when I need to clean up the environment.

Thanks really appreciate your help!
Ennio

[image]

Comment: When you run the command to create the policy (aws iam create-policy ...) do you get a success response? Also, maybe you are checking in a different account please validate your credentials

Comment: Yes you are right! They ended up in another account :-(
If you want I can mark your answer as correct. Can you write it instead this simple comment?

Comment: Great! I just have added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After run the command

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicyTest --policy-document file://iam_policy.json
```

you get a response like this:

```
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicyTest",
        "PolicyId": "ANPA2BMVX57HOOWXXXXXX",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:policy/AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicyTest",
        "Path": "/",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v1",
        "AttachmentCount": 0,
        "PermissionsBoundaryUsageCount": 0,
        "IsAttachable": true,
        "CreateDate": "2022-01-XXTXX:XX:XX+00:00",
        "UpdateDate": "2022-01-XXTXX:XX:XX+00:00"
    }
}
```

Make sure the account you are using when running the command is the same you are checking on the web console.